# CUDA Kernel parameter incompatibility

Tags: c, cuda

I don't know what went wrong, I want to add the two vectors together, but I get an error.
I looked at some tutorials but I don't see the problem
This is my error:

> argument of type "int **" is incompatible with parameter of type "int *"

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>


__global__ void addKernel(int* c, int* a, int* b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

int main()
{

    const int arraySize = 5;
    int a[arraySize] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b[arraySize] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int c[arraySize] = { 0 };

    int *d_a[arraySize];
    int *d_b[arraySize];
    int *d_c[arraySize];

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, arraySize*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, arraySize*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, arraySize*sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, arraySize*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, arraySize*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 block(5, 1, 1);
    dim3 grid(1, 1, 1);

    addKernel<<<block,grid>>>(d_c, d_a, d_b);

    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, arraySize*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);

    printf("{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {%d,%d,%d,%d,%d}\n",
        c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is *exactly* as described by the compiler. `d_a`, `d_b`, and `d_C` are arrays of pointers, not pointers. If you fix that problem, the code *might* compile

Comment: @talonmies Would you like to provide a short answer to this post? I would upvote it.

Comment: @JackOLantern: Part of me dies every time I answer a question like this one, but OK.

Comment: @talonmies I understand that this is not an interesting question and perhaps not very useful for the whole community. But to grow up a child you need to teach him/her walking. Getting some help, perhaps he/she will be able to put more intriguing posts in the future. Maybe not :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler warning is extremely clear. This:

```
int *d_a[arraySize];
int *d_b[arraySize];
int *d_c[arraySize];
```

is incorrect and almost certainly not what you want. You have declared each of `d_a`, `d_b` and `d_c` to be *arrays of pointers*, which conflicts with the kernel declaration (and makes little sense because it looks like you only need a single pointer for the device versions of `a`, `b` and `c`.

I suspect what you meant was actually

```
int *d_a;
int *d_b;
int *d_c;
```

If you make that change, the code should probably compile.